# React Router redirect using alternate route configuration

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to use the alternate configuration of React Router: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md#alternate-configuration

However, I'm having trouble getting redirect to work. I tried this:

```
const routes = {
  childRoutes: [
    { path: '/test', component: Test },
  ],
  component: App,
  path: '/',
  redirect: {
    from: '/',
    to: '/test',
  },
};
```

As far as I could tell, there is no documentation for this. Does the functionality exist? How should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the sample code in the link you posted, with the sample above (in [Preserving URLs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md#preserving-urls)), I think both samples refer to setting the same routes (the only difference probably is that the last one uses the *Alternate Configuration*). And we can infer that the current way of making redirects is using the `onEnter` function.

For instance, if you want this (using *JSX*):

```
<Redirect from="messages/:id" to="/messages/:id" />
```

And you use the *Alternate Configuration*, you'll have to write it like this:

```
{ path: 'messages/:id',
  onEnter: function (nextState, replaceState) {
    replaceState(null, '/messages/' + nextState.params.id)
  }
}
```

**Update**: Your particular case is special, because you want to redirect from `/`, so you might want to try using [IndexRedirect](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/API.md#indexredirect) or [indexroute](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/API.md#indexroute).

Comment: Thanks @Protron. This didn't work exactly but using `onEnter` got me thinking. Here's how I solved it: `onEnter: (nextState, transition) => {
      if (nextState.location.pathname === '/') {
        transition.to('/test', null);
      }
    },`

Comment: @Chris Nice! But in case you are interested in finding other solutions you might want to take a look at the update in my answer.

Comment: transition isn't one of the arguments coming into the function for me. I'm having the same issue trying to redirect `/` to something else along with a bunch of others. This is much more complicated than <Redirect>, but then you can do `require.ensure` :/.